# Are babel and uglify.js installed when we install webpack 4

Tags: javascript, webpack

I was learning `webpack` and babel and majority of tutorials on YouTube teach to install `webpack` and babel separately. But I tried to install `webpack` only without installing babel( and uglify.js). So, I used `webpack` then it automatically `uglified` and changed my ES6 code into ES5. The question is Does `webpack` 4 use `uglify.js` and babel behind the scenes even if I do not install them manually?

Answer (score 0):

Webpack doesn’t know how to make the transformation, so you would need to install `babel` dependencies. Also for `uglify.js`, you would need to install the plugin. see the links I posted below.

https://webpack.js.org/plugins/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/

https://webpack.js.org/plugins/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/